# What this vector equation means

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I have this equation

> K = (A, B, C) / |A x B|

- A, B, C are 3D vectors.
- K should be number, not vector.

How is this calculated, or what this expression means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ (A, B, C) $ seems to be the [mixed product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product), the volume of the parallelepiped defined by $A,B,C$.

In this case, $K$ is the height of the parallelepiped because $|A\times B|$ is the area of one side.

Comment: And what could be the order of operations? A * (B x C) or (A x B) * C

Comment: @MartinPerry, changing the order in that way does not change the value.